# fade in a jquery UI progressbar

Tags: jquery

Example site: http://johanberntsson.se/dev/fotosida/

Relevant code:

```
jQuery.fn.center = function () {

    this.css("position","absolute");
            this.css("top", (($(window).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop() + "px");
            this.css("left", (($(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
            return this;
}


$.each(data, function (index, val) {
    $('<img/>').data({
        exif: val.exif
    }).attr({
        'src': 'fotosida/' + val.full_url + "?" + new Date().getTime(),
        'class': 'mainimages'
    }).css({
        'margin': '10px auto',
        'display': 'block'
    }).hide().appendTo('body');
});

$('#progressbar').center().fadeIn(500);

var i = 1;

$('body img.mainimages').load(function () {
    $("#progressbar").progressbar({
        value: (i / data.length) * 100
    });
    i++;
    if(i > data.length) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#progressbar').fadeOut(500, function () {
                $('body img.mainimages').fadeIn(200);
            });
        }, 200);
    }
});
```

What I don't understand is why the loader doesn't fade in. It just pops up like I was using `show()`

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess it is because you aren't creating the progress bar until the first image loads.  So, it *does* fade in, but it is an empty div at that point.  Once the first div loads, the progress bar is initialized.

Try doing this:

```
$('#progressbar').progressbar({ value: 0 }).center().fadeIn(500);
```

**As an added note**, if you use this as your `#progressbar` css, you won't need a special `center()` function, and the progress bar will remain centered if the window is resized:

```
#progressbar {
    display: none;
    width: 900px;
    height: 2em;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -450px;
    margin-top: -1em;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}
```

Comment: No problem.  Note my CSS suggestion I added later.

Comment: Nice addon, think ill use that since, as you mentioned, works for window resizing as well :-)